R3F Providing context of GLTF imported meshes causes typescript error when subscribing to and rendering meshes
So I'm rendering out instanced meshes in my scene using the code below
interface IInstanceContext {
    [key: string]: Mesh<BufferGeometry<NormalBufferAttributes>, Material | Material[], Object3DEventMap>
}
const context = createContext<IInstanceContext>({} as IInstanceContext)
export function Instances({ children, ...props }) {
  const { nodes } = useGLTF('/models/digivice.glb') as GLTFResult
  const instances = useMemo(
    () => ({
      DigiviceBodyLights: nodes.Digivice_Body_Lights_0,
      DigiviceBodyBody: nodes.Digivice_Body_Body_0,
      DigiviceBodyScreen: nodes.Digivice_Body_Screen_0,
      DigiviceBodyScreenCorner: nodes.Digivice_Body_Screen_Corner_0,
      ButtonsButtons: nodes.Buttons_Buttons_0,
      AntennaAntenna: nodes.Antenna_Antenna_0,
    }),
    [nodes]
  )
  return (
    <Merged meshes={instances} {...props}>
      {(instances) => <context.Provider value={instances} children={children} />}
    </Merged>
  )
}

//See if we can possibly remove the need for provider, 
export function DigiviceMesh(props: JSX.IntrinsicElements['group']) {
  const instances = useContext(context)
  return (
    <group {...props} dispose={null} >
      <group rotation={[-Math.PI / 2, 0, 0]} scale={10}>
        <instances.DigiviceBodyLights />
        <instances.DigiviceBodyBody />
        <instances.DigiviceBodyScreen />
        <instances.DigiviceBodyScreenCorner />
      </group>
      <instances.ButtonsButtons rotation={[-Math.PI / 2, 0, 0]} scale={0.1} />
      <instances.AntennaAntenna rotation={[-Math.PI, -Math.PI / 6, 0]} scale={0.1} />
    </group>
  )
}

useGLTF.preload('/models/digivice.glb')

The code itself runs fine, but I added an interface to cast the initial context state to to avoid typescript errors.
 interface IInstanceContext { [key: string]: Mesh<BufferGeometry<NormalBufferAttributes>, Material | Material[], Object3DEventMap> }
This could probably be simpler (maybe just typed to mesh) but regardless it should work. The issue is when rendering this out in the DigiviceMesh component I get a type error

'instances.DigiviceBodyLights' cannot be used as a JSX component.
Its type 'Mesh<BufferGeometry, Material | Material[], Object3DEventMap>' is not a valid JSX element type.

I can't for the life of me figure out how to resolve correctly. If I change the IInstanceContext to take jsx elements that causes the same issue.
Alternatively I could render out each individual mesh as a <mesh> jsx element and assign the mesh directly, but that doubles the gpu load for some reason, so would prefer to keep the current implementation and just find a way to make typescript play nice.

Okay, figured out this behavior is more so emerging from drei's <Merged/> Helper component and how it forwards the mesh references. Replacing my previous IInstanceContext Interface with
type ContextType = Record<string, React.ForwardRefExoticComponent<JSX.IntrinsicElements['mesh']>>;
Made typescript happy in my case.
